# Nexus 10 hi-res resources

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-resources, nexus-10

I'm testing my app on the nexus 10 and I'm wondering how to provide background resources for the same.

To elaborate, the problem is that the Nexus 10 sports a **2560x1600 resolution** but falls in the [**xhdpi**](https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW) category, which is the same category as the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 4. I am trying to understand how can I provide a 2560x1600 resolution background image specific to the Nexus 10 instead of defaulting to a Galaxy Nexus background which is designed for a 1280x720 like screen. Typically I would do that by putting the background image in the respective drawable folder (here drawable-xhdpi) and let android automatically pick the right resources.

**Possible solution**: Should I put the  2560x1600 resolution image in a drawable-sw720p-xhdpi folder? Is it correct to categorise the nexus 10 as a sw720dp device (10+") with xhdpi characteristics?

Comment: Your possible solution will most likely work. However, your image will eat up roughly 16MB of memory just for the background. If you're not using much memory for anything else, this might not be a problem, but otherwise you might want to rethink it. Maybe a 9patch would be more suitable?

Comment: Good point, but the app backgrounds are just like wallpapers and won't look good as a 9patch, any idea on how android handles wallpapers for their launcher on the nexus 10?

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe it's open source, though, so you should be able to find out that way.

Comment: thanks, will get right on it.

Comment: You solve it at final?

Answer (score -3):

The Nexus 10 should be xxhdpi. Just make a folder res/drawable-xxhdpi, res/drawable-sw720p-xxhdpi etc. and it should work.

Comment: The nexus 10 is a xhdpi device (~300 dpi), link to that is in the question.

Comment: No, It should be res/drawable-sw720p-xhdpi